# Software Update shows multiple Command Line Tools updates for Xcode versions not even installed

Tags: xcode, software-update

Following problems with the GNU gcc compiler installed through brew (messages about missing libraries that suddenly started appearing) I had to reinstall Xcode 13.4.1 yesterday.

This morning I’m now seeing several updates for Command Line Tools, for other versions of Xcode:

[image: xcode updates]

Why is this showing? And how do I dismiss those? gcc is now working fine so I don’t want to mess anything up!

Comment: Click More Info… & download only the latest one. After install reboot & check again. Report back.

Comment: @tetsujin it worked! how can I mark your comment as an answer? (new to posting on SE)

Comment: I can put it in as an answer so you can mark ti accepted. It was a bit of a guess, that the system would be smart enough to forget the out of date ones once the 'new' update was applid, otherwise I'd have put it straight in as an answer. Glad it worked for you :)

Comment: well it was a logical suggestion, and it worked ; i think it qualifies as an answer ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The system is likely to be able to shake itself out once the newest update is applied…

Click 'More Info…' set it to do only the latest update, then afterwards reboot & check again. It ought to have cleared the backlog.

Comment: this worked ; all the other updates disappeared after the reboot, thanks!