# Should I install all versions of Xcode CL tools update?

Tags: mac, command-line, xcode, software-update

I got a prompt to install updates.

- MacOS 12.4
- I don't have XCode installed
- just the XCode command line tools, version: 13.0.0.0.1.1627064638

All these updates seem to be different versions of the same tool. Shouldn't I just install the latest one, or do I need to install them all? (By default, all of the versions were checked for download).

[image]

Comment: We might need to know what your goal is here to answer. Why not uninstall Xcode and skip all the command line tools?

Comment: @bmike well i installed it because my VCScode keeps bugging me to do it, it says its not able to use git o/w. My goal was to just install the update, but because I don't have unlimited internet or unlimited disk space, I thought I'd ask someone who knows better, before installing them all :(

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What is the version of Xcode that you have currently installed and what is the version of macOS that you are running?

Comment: @NimeshNeema I have MacOS 12.4 and as it turns out, I don't have XCode installed but just the XCode command line tools, version: 13.0.0.0.1.1627064638.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need the updates one way or another.

Since you don’t have Xcode installed, you could simplify things by [uninstalling the command line tools](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/310470/5472) and then install one clean package.

```
rm /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
#optionally restart and check for updates before reinstalling
xcode-select --install
```

Running all the updates is the other path forward that’s easy. [This is expected when each update is a delta](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/442210/) even when Xcode does the install (which adds complexity beyond what you require) and not “the whole install whether things change each version or not” type installer.

If the goal is minimizing downloads you can set up a local caching service in the future so you only download each update once for the entire network.

- [What is content caching on Mac?](https://support.apple.com/en-ie/guide/mac-help/mchl9388ba1b/mac)
- [Set up content caching on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-ie/guide/mac-help/mchl3b6c3720/mac)

Also, this is often worse on betas where Apple will test updates so you might be part of testing things or the beta packages don’t get seeded globally so you have to do more downloads than once things slow down after general release.